# What is the difference betweem ` and ' in bash?

Tags: bash

Today I noticed if I run:

```
ldd `which bash`
```

I get the expected output.
But when I run

```
ldd 'which bash'
```

I get error `./which bash: No such file or directory.`

So what is the difference between the two similar looking symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ` is named a *backquote*, to evaluate a command.

The backquote is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g.

```
foo=`command`
```

The

```
foo=$(command)
```

syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside `$()` is less surprising, and `$()` is easier to nest.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

---

The single quote ' is used to prevent shell expansion from strings:

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
> [when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)